# CSV upload parsing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv

Could someone advise with the following CSV parsing issue:

CSV:

```
Robert,Lobos,lobs@email.com
Klein,Kleinerer,kln@gmail.com
Gross,Grosserer,gr@grosserer.de
```

Method:

```
def upload
  if (params[:contactList])

    csv_content = params[:contactList].read
    @recipients = {}
    CSV.parse(csv_content) do |row|
      @recipients[row[0]] = {'forename' => row[0], 'surname' => row[1], 'email' => row[2]}
    end

    render 'index'
  end
end
```

Target is to render the values in the template as following:

```
<% @recipients.each do |recipient| %>
  <option value="test"><%= recipient['forename'] %> <%= recipient['surname'] %> (<%= recipient['email'] %>)</option>
<% end %>
```

Currently throws up with:

> can't convert String into Integer

What's the best way/quickfix to achieve the above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To iterate a hash with a block, the `key` and `value` of the hash entries are provided to the block.

```
<% @recipients.each do |recipient| %>
```

should be

```
<% @recipients.each do |key, recipient| %>
```